# .NET 4.7 xunit test project fails to build when referencing a .NET Standard 1.6 project

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-devops

So I have a simple solution with 2x projects:

- .NET Standard 1.6 class library
- .NET 4.7 framework class library with xUnit for testing.

[image]

Now when I try and build (in VS2017) locally, all is ok.

When I build on Visual Studio Online/Team Services, I get heaps of errors:-

```
[command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build d:\a\1\s\src\Hornet.Services\Hornet.Services.csproj -c release /p:Version=1.0.0
Microsoft(R) Build Engine version 15.1.1012.6693
Copyright(C) Microsoft Corporation.All rights reserved.

Hornet.Services -> d:\a\1\s\src\Hornet.Services\bin\release\netstandard1.6\Hornet.Services.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

/\___ Works! (Not the NS1.6 version)

next project to build in the same solution ...

```
[command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build d:\a\1\s\tests\Hornet.Services.Tests\Hornet.Services.Tests.csproj -c release /p:Version= 1.0.0
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.1012.6693
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.All rights reserved.

Hornet.Services -> d:\a\1\s\src\Hornet.Services\bin\release\netstandard1.6\Hornet.Services.dll
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference.Could not locate the assembly "Castle.Core, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=407dd0808d44fbdc, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk.If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\tests\Hornet.Services.Tests\Hornet.Services.Tests.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "FizzWare.NBuilder, Version=5.0.0.138, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\tests\Hornet.Services.Tests\Hornet.Services.Tests.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "FluentValidation, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7de548da2fbae0f0, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\tests\Hornet.Services.Tests\Hornet.Services.Tests.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Google.Apis, Version=1.28.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\tests\Hornet.Services.Tests\Hornet.Services.Tests.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Google.Apis.Core, Version=1.28.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\tests\Hornet.Services.Tests\Hornet.Services.Tests.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Google.Apis.PlatformServices, Version=1.28.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\tests\Hornet.Services.Tests\Hornet.Services.Tests.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Google.Apis.QPXExpress.v1, Version=1.28.0.554, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [d:\a\1\s\tests\Hornet.Services.Tests\Hornet.Services.Tests.csproj]

.. <lots more snipped>
```

My local version of dotnet info is

```
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.4)

Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.4
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  af1e6684fd

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.15063
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4
```

while i *think* VSTS is using `1.0.2`

```
==============================================================================
 Task         : .NET Core
 Description  : Build, test and publish using dotnet core command-line.
 Version      : 1.0.2
 Author       : Microsoft Corporation
 Help         : [More Information] (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
```

Comment: Try with VS2017 Preview installed on your agent

Comment: Do you mean `Agent Queue: Hosted VS2017` ? That is what the current value has been.

Comment: Not quite! I meant create a private agent which has the preview version of vs2017 installed! Not difficult, but a bit of a faff to get that working! Looking at the release notes here https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes#dotnetcoreimprovements15P3 framework/standard/core interop was only brought in with preview3. Not sure what tooling was updated to allow this. Hopefully someone more in the know can help you. In the mean time you could create a VSTS task to install the latest preview net core tools before your build step and see of that helps!

Answer (score 2):

I believe I found my answer -> I was trying to do the following steps all targeting **.NET CORE** :

1. Restore
2. Build
3. Test
4. Pack

but these are all .NET Core steps .. and the test project is a .NET 4.7 project.

So I didn't build the test project ... which was why it was erroring! Damn it.

Much embarrassment.

So the TL;DR; / Takeaway here is to double check the VSTS Build Steps and make sure they are targeting the correct items.